# Wordpress empty search results

Tags: wordpress

I have created my search page which works fine.

But I have a problem:

When I do an empty search, it displays some posts and pages, but not all of them.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : (in ***function.php***)

```
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'YOUR_POST_TYPE'));
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, but what is the code/query I need to display all the posts and pages ?

Comment: you mean all custom posts and pages?